# How to read structured binary data from a file?

Tags: python, file-io, binaryfiles

The following C++ code writes a header to a file:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Header
{
    uint16_t name;
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t padding;
    uint32_t width, height;
    uint32_t depth1, depth2;
    float dMin, dMax;
};

int main()
{

  Header header;
  header.name = *reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>("XO");
  header.type = true;
  header.width  = (uint32_t)512;
  header.height = (uint32_t)600;
  header.depth1  = (uint32_t)16;
  header.depth2 = (uint32_t)25;
  header.dMin = 5.0;
  header.dMax = 8.6;

  FILE* f = fopen("header.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(Header), 1, f);
}
```

I am looking to read these `header.bin` files using Python. In C++ I would be doing something like:

```
fread(&header, sizeof(Header), 1, f)
```

But I'm unsure how to read the bytes and convert them into the corresponding fields that the Header struct has in Python?

Comment: Python has an aptly named ``struct`` module suitable for such tasks.

Comment: Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module in the standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to define the binary layout of a C-like struct and de-/serialise it:

```py
import struct

# Format String describing the data layout
layout = "H B x 2L 2L 2f"

# Object representing the layout, including size
header = struct.Struct(layout)

with open("header.bin", "rb") as in_stream:
    print(header.unpack(in_stream.read(header.size))
```

The `layout` is a [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) describing the fields in-order, e.g. `H` for `uint16_t`, `B` for `uint8_t`, `x` for a pad byte, and so on.

Comment: this is probably the cleanest approach

Comment: Be sure to precede the layout with the appropriate endianness character if the data can be affected by endianness. (see the documentation for the struct module). Typically < or > for forcing little or big-endianness, respectively

Comment: Thank you and yes I needed to add the little-endian `layout = "<H B x 2L 2L 2f"`

Comment: FYI `ctypes.Structure` also supports bit fields, which `struct` does not, if that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with Python's [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), somewhat so you can share the Header header

Create a class from `ctypes.Structure` to map the types

```py
import ctypes

class StructHeader(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("name", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ...
    ]
```

And create a function which does what you want with a signature like

```c
int header(struct Header &buffer)
{
    // open the file and write to buffer
    // opportunity for other features
}
```

Then you can compile a [shared object](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) to read it which returns that type

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,your_soname \
    -o library_name file_list library_list
```

And call out with `ctypes.CDLL` to read the headers

```py
header = ctypes.CDLL("mylib.so.1").header  # function named header
header.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(StructHeader)]
header.restype  = ctypes.c_int

# allocate struct for write
buffer = StructHeader()

# call out to function to write buffer
header(buffer)
```