# Read shared memory with python

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am getting data in /dev/shm directory which is created with `c`.

```
soaib@soaib-desktop:/dev/shm$ ls
PGR_CTL_0x1E10_18474649  PHS-5536  psm_50d4cfd1
```

Now, I want to read the data from the shared memory with `python`, for example, I want to read what is in "PGR_CTL_0x1E10_18474649".

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: does `open("/dev/shm/PGR_CTL_0x1E10_18474649")` work?

Comment: I can open the file. But it seems like binary file (not readable)

Comment: If you have a non-text file, you need to understand its format (which could be _anything_); reading the documentation for or collaborating with the author(s) of the upstream program are going to be your best bet here!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read structured binary data from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809916/how-to-read-structured-binary-data-from-a-file)